# Update quantity showing error in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, fatal-error

I update my shopping cart but it showing me fatal error:

[image]

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Phrase, string given, 
called in /home/uscvuy8bk5zu/public_html/domain.name/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php on line 121 
and defined in /home/uscvuy8bk5zu/public_html/domain.name/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php:51
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/uscvuy8bk5zu/public_html/domain.name/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/ShippingAddressManagement.php(121): Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException->__construct('Please note tha...') 
#1 /home/uscvuy8bk5zu/public_html/domain.name/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/ShippingAssignment/ShippingProcessor.php(66): Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingAddressManagement->assign('15', Object(Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address)) 
#2 /home/uscvuy8bk5zu/public_html/domain.name/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/ShippingAssignment/ShippingAssignmentPro in /home/uscvuy8bk5zu/public_html/domain.name/vendor/magento/framework/Exception/InputException.php on line 51
```

Comment: Were you trying to delete the last item in the cart ? Do you have **Minimum order amount ** set in the Admin configuration ?

Comment: I have set "minimum Order amount" in the admin configuration.

Comment: please compile once

Answer (score 0):

This is an existing issue with Magento 2.1 thats occurs when the minimum order amount is set in the admin configuration and when the user tries to remove the last item in the cart. Refer this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6151)

One of the possible solutions is to follow the below steps.

Create a plugin

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\Quote">
    <plugin name="min-orderamount-skip-delete" type="Namespace\ModuleName\Model\QuoteAfter" sortOrder="10"/>
</type>
```

Include the below **after** method in the newly created plugin class QuoteAfter.php

```
public function afterValidateMinimumAmount()
{
    $actionName = $this->request->getActionName();
    if($actionName === 'delete') {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Nikin, Can you explain in detail?

Comment: Quick question before detailing it. Are you by any chance familiar with Magento 2 module development ( create a skeleton custom module and plugins) ?

Comment: I am familiar with magento 2 module development and I saw this solution from above link: http://prntscr.com/lt6b77 but I didn't understand this.